# ASP.NET MVC2 +file uploading (HttpPostedFileBase class)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, file-upload, httppostedfilebase

I have problem with uploading my file. I want to upload it from my **edit view:**

```
    <% 
    using (Html.BeginForm("edit","profile",FormMethod.Post, new { enctype="multipart/form-data" }))
    {%>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

    <%: ViewData["ErrorMessage"] %>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input type="file" id="Image" name="Image" />
            <label id="LabelErrorImage" class="errorMessage" />
        </div> 

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="return Validate(); return false;"/>
        </p>
    </fieldset>

<% } %>
```

I want to use **HttpPostedFileBase** class. My edit action:

```
[Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Edit(string id, HttpPostedFileBase file, FormCollection formValues)
        {
                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {

                        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                        {
                            CustomHelpers.createFolder();
                            var tmpPath = MyConfig.UPLOAD_FILE_PATH + "/" + Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString();
                            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(MyConfig.UPLOAD_FILE_PATH), "Avatar");
                            var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                            file.SaveAs(path);
                            user.Image = "Avatar";
                        }
                        adventureDB.SaveChanges();

                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
        }
```

But I always have empty the file object, why????? Do you have any ideas, suggestions why it can work like that? Maybe there is problem how I pass on the file value to my Edit action?

---

**EDIT:**
 IT IS REALLY STRANGE AS EVEN WHEN I REMOVE
  `using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Profile",FormMethod.Get, new { enctype="multipart/form-data" }))`

The page source still has:

```
<body>

    <form method="post" action="6111e591-b92d-4bcb-b214-ab8f664b35f9" id="form1">
```

I mean I can not change the  tag but have no idea why :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:-

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id, HttpPostedFileBase file, 
  FormCollection formValues)
```

to:-

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id, HttpPostedFileBase image, 
  FormCollection formValues)
```

as the name of your input is `image`

```
 <input type="file" id="Image" name="Image" />
```

**edit**
To be honest something else is stopping the binding of image. Is this the whole form that you have posted?

A few things to test

1. You have HTTPOST decorating your method twice, although I don't believe this should make a difference.
2. View the source and make sure there is nothing else named `name=image` in the source.
3. Make sure you empty your cache and make sure source is correct before testing again
4. Try using `<form action="/profile/index" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`
5. Judging by your last edit you have a problem with master pages/layout? Is this a mvc/webforms hybrid?

Comment: Yes true, I have changed it but it still has null :/

Comment: No it is not all code as it is very long but I noticed that it does not matter what I write in my view as always it is redirecting to the same function. Maybe because I use Master site and it uses a mechanism which I do not know?

Comment: Further more I have 2 forms in the source code:  <form method="post" action="6111e591-b92d-4bcb-b214-ab8f664b35f9" id="form1">

<div class="aspNetHidden">

<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUJMjIyODQ4MTE2ZGQ0zXwQxrpoQd+by+EOC4qY3mQAo7zW2FgvbThGQUWMVQ==" /></div>
and then the second which I wrote in view: 
<form action="/Profile/Edit" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">

Comment: Yes I have found the mistake!!!! In Master.Site it default creates form and there can not be nested forms as the second one is ignored! I have lost so many time to found it out! Thanks for help!

Comment: No worries, perhaps you could mark this question as answered, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The solution of this problem when:

1. We use Master.Site,
2. We want to upload file in a view,
3. We are sure that it should work but we all the time has null,

Then:

1. Guys were right - I had wrong name in my view - check it!
2. Check source code of your view and if you have 2 < form > tags you should remove the < form > tag from Master site as then the second one is ignored!

Now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your view you named the file input 'image' but your action method accepts a parameter called 'file'. Rename one of those and it should work.

Comment: Yes, but I have changed it now and still the same :/